# How to deal with questions related to 3rd party software

Tags: discussion

Check [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2793/259) its about [Quorum Wallet](https://quorumwallet.com/faq), in the site itself that are stating

> Warning: alpha software intended for developers only!

The question is somewhat related to creating a **Version 3 of the Ethereum wallet format file**

Does this goes to `out-of-scope` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no truly "official" software to begin with, I'd say that any technical questions relating directly to tools for Ethereum are within scope. Just because a tool is in alpha, doesn't mean that it should be out of scope, either. This question is more about how to generate a Ethereum wallet file than it is about a particular wallet anyway.

If we start drawing arbitrary bounds around what is or is not 3rd party software, it could lead to difficult decisions in the future. Are technical issues interacting with DApps off topic? What about issues with "3rd party" clients like Parity?

Comment: Okay, this question is related to Ethereum wallet, in that case can we recommend a rephrase? Clients like parity will definitely come under Ethereum since it deals with the Blockchain, but this particular software is a wrapper, i guess. I agree that DApps are in-topic so we can go ahead with this.

Comment: I personally think the phrasing is fine, but if you think you can improve it, go ahead

Comment: Challenge accepted, but i guess that will change OPs question drastically.

Answer (score 0):

The network is owned, run and monitored by everyone, but controlled by anyone.

Therefore, everything is third party software. There is nothing official by definition. Of course, there are reference clients, but they are just technical examples of the yellow paper definition.

I clearly see no reason why anything should be *out of scope* of our site if it's related to Ethereum, its blockchain, smart contracts, decentralized applications, including the Swarm and Whisper protocols.